# How to change the result of exporting to Excel format a report with subreport and chart

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

We have a report which contains 6 pages (I have used page breaks). Each page has few sub-reports and few charts. We are exporting it as *Excel*.

When we are trying to print one sheet the page is breaking into multiple pages dividing the sub-reports and charts in middle. Is there some best way or thumb rule to follow in order to make reports print friendly.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

Posting here in case somebody is struck with same issue
Need to set these properties in report

net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.width =1 and
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.fit.height=1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the Ribbon (I have Excel 2007) go to `View` tab, then select `Page Break Preview` and drag page borders as you desire. These settings are saved together with the workbook, so on the next reopen page breaks will remain as set.

Comment: thanks for replying peter.But my I am looking for some jasper-reports features/best practices. so that i don't have to modify each time the work book is generated.